# Excel 2007 line chart won't add dates past 2014 when using full data range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

For reference, the Excel file in question: https://ufile.io/mlczqpkb

When I try and include the entire range of dates and river heights, it always cuts it off at 2014. If I slide the ranges down a few, it will actually include 2021.

I've formatted the dates as properly as I can, I've made sure the heights are numbers, I've expanded the x-axis maximum manually (I've fiddled with every format axis option), I've checked for extra spaces, it's nowhere near the data point limit, I've triple-checked the range formula, and I don't know what else to try.

I realize this is a bare-bones way to try and describe the problem, so please let me know if you have any other questions.

[image: Screen capture of offending chart]

[image: Screen capture of offending data]

Comment: The problem is dates as graph axis labels consume a lot of display area, so excel tends to be conservative in assigning them. Try setting your  base interval to years not months, decreasing the major unit to 1 or 2 years, moving the chart to its own sheet (for more display area) and lastly put your own maximum bound past the last date in the data e.g. 2022 or 2024.

Comment: @Mobus I appreciate the reply. The issue with that is then it stacks data points on top of each other making it jagged and crazy: https://ufile.io/cur6z9c3 (.png screenshot)

Comment: Realizing now that this might just not be the best way to represent this data.

Comment: Its not really on top of each other, its just that the timeline is so condensed that the data is squashed together. If you zoom in (adjust the minimum bound) the data points would separate. You could try a scatter plot (which unfortunately translates the date in the chart config to Excel date serial numbers (number of days since 1 Jan 1900). Not a train smash but a little more confusing, You do seem to get more control over the major units etc.

Comment: In the chart with "stacked" points (the .png screenshot), it looks like the major unit of the horizontal axis is years or months. Change this to days.

Comment: When you make an XY chart with dates as the X values, the axis labels (dates) will be formatted as dates. If you want to specify axis limits, then you need to enter the date as a general number. But the axis labels are fine.